Can anyone explain how this creates a max heap in C#?
I know this is a min heap
var minHeap = new PriorityQueue<int, int>();

But why does this comparer result in a max heap?
var maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<int, int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));

I've tried looking into the documentation for Comparer and I see that it takes a Comparison delegate. The delegate determines how two elements compare to each other. y.CompareTo(x) will return 0 if equal, <0 if y is less than x and >0 if y is greater than x. What I'm confused about is how this influences ordering in the priority queue. Is it because a greater comparison value (e.g. y.CompareTo(x) returning a greater value) result in a higher priority?

Did you notice that the order of arguments is inverted? (x, y) => y.CompareTo(x) instead of (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y).

Imagine you're building a binary heap. You insert the first item, 1, and then you go to insert the second item, 2. If it's a min-heap, then 2 should become the left child. If it's a max heap then 2 becomes the new root and 1 is the left child.
So, let's see:
minheap_insert(heap, y)
    // min heap
    x = heap.PeekMin();  // get the heap root
    if (x.CompareTo(y) > 0)
    {
        // heap root is larger than the new item
        // Make the new item the root of the heap
    }

maxheap_insert(heap, y)
    // max heap
    x = heap.PeekMin(); // get the heap root
    if (y.CompareTo(x) > 0)
    {
        // new item is larger than the heap root
        // Make the new item the root of the heap
    }

